# How do I use Fluent NHibernate to map a self-referencing folder hierarchy?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, mapping

I have a folder hierarchy represented by the following class:

```
public class Folder
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual Folder ParentFolder { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Folder> SubFolders { get; set; }
}
```

In other words, each `Folder` can belong to a `ParentFolder`, as well as have `SubFolders` under it. I'm using Fluent NHibernate's `Automapper` and automatically generating the database schema using `SchemaExport`. I get the following table when I try to save some test folders:

```
Id | Name                        | ParentFolder_id | Folder_id
----------------------------------------------------------------
1  | Root Folder (has children)  | NULL            | NULL
2  | Root Folder (no children)   | NULL            | NULL
3  | Sub Folder                  | 1               | NULL
4  | Sub Sub Folder              | 2               | NULL
```

So far so good, the `ParentFolder_id` column is being set correctly, although I don't know why it created another `Folder_id` column. Now, when I try to run the following code:

```
using (var session = SessionFactory.OpenSession())
{
    // I'm using NHibernate 3
    var rootFolder = session.Query<Folder>()
                            .Where(x => x.Name.StartsWith("root").First();

    Console.WriteLine(rootFolder.SubFolders.Count());
}
```

The count returned is 0, and the following SQL is executed:

```
SELECT count(Id) FROM [Folder] WHERE Folder_id = 1
```

This SQL statement is wrong. It should be doing:

```
SELECT count(Id) FROM [Folder] WHERE ParentFolder_id = 1
```

Can anyone tell me why Fluent NHibernate is creating the extra `Folder_id` column and querying on it, and how I can fix it so that it properly queries the `ParentFolder_id` column instead? I've tried the following override with no luck:

```
public class FolderOverride : IAutoMappingOverride<Folder>
{
    public void Override(AutoMapping<Folder> mapping)
    {
        mapping.HasMany(x => x.SubFolders).Inverse(); // I thought inverse might fix it, but no dice
        mapping.References(x => x.ParentFolder);
    }
}
```

Comment: What version of fluent-NH are you running? As far as i can tell, this should be supported out of the box as of version 1.1 : http://fluentnhibernate.lighthouseapp.com/projects/33236/tickets/115-self-referencing-relationships

Comment: I'm using the head of the trunk as of a few days ago.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you will have to specify the columns on your mapping overrides.

```
mapping.HasMany(x => x.SubFolders).KeyColumn("ParentFolder_id");
```

Comment: Thanks, that did it. I just had to make the two sides of the relationship were using the same column: `mapping.HasMany(x => x.SubFolders).KeyColumn("ParentFolder_id");` and `mapping.References(x => x.ParentFolder).Column("ParentFolder_id");`.